# Flexbox not working in Chrome

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a basic flexbox situation for chrome in scss in order to align some items in a form. I have stripped it down in order to get what is happening

```
fieldset{

    &.fullname{
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        background:pink;
        width:100%;
        min-height:2em;

        label{
            width:45%;

            &:first-child{
                margin-right:10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <fieldset class="fullname">

        <label>item 1</label>
        <label>item 2</label>
    </fieldset>
```

This works absolutely fine in Firefox but for some reason chrome (version 56) is not having it and only makes the label items stack over each other instead of side by side.

What is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Add a wrapper between the fieldset and its children, fieldset won't work as a flex container

Comment: that fixed it! I would have never guessed. Thanks

Comment: Hours and hours I've been trying to solve this.  Thanks @LGSon